# How to make a slave the controlling terminal in linux?

Tags: c, linux, pty

Can someone please explain to me why `ioctl` fails to change set the slave as the controlling terminal in the following code

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    int master, slave, status;
    int client_socket;
    /*
        created the socket and connected to the remote server
    */

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to fork process");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(master);
        if (openpty(&master, &slave, slave_name, NULL,NULL) != 0)
        {
            perror("child process failed to create a pty");
        }
        if (setsid() < 0)
        {
            perror("failed to start new session");
        }
        if (ioctl(slave, TIOCSCTTY, 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("failed set to slave as controlling tty");
        }
        execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        close(slave);
        // PARENT 
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    }
    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

On successful connection to the remote server I get the error

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

and the forked process still works.

I checked the controlling terminal before and after running the client program and got the same value `dev/pty/7`

Can someone explain how to fix this error?

Comment: You have `close(master);` before you've initialized `master`. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: You need to create the pty before calling `fork()`. Then you can close the master in the child process and close the slave in the parent process. If you're already familiar with using pipes, it's very similar.

Comment: And you have `close(slave)` before you've initialized `slave` — that is not going to lead to happiness in the long run.